# get storage account names for subscription then create a name based on the results

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

My naming convention for storage account has to have a number at the end of the storage account name eg storageaccount01

When I create a new account I need to make sure I dont duplicate any storage name. I cant use the uniqueid for this project , it has to be the above naming convention.

Using powershell what is the best way to get the subscription storage accounts then check the names of the storage accounts and then create a storage account on the next available number . so for example if i retrieve the names of the storage accounts and we have storageaccount01, storageaccount02, this means the next available one will be storageaccount03. Whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` to retrieve all storage accounts for your subscription
2. Filter your desired account name using the  `Where-Object` cmdlet
3. Remove the account name to retrieve a list of numbers using e. g. `-replace`
4. Determine the maximum number using the `Measure-Object` cmdlet
5. Finally create the new storage account name using a format string

**Example:**

```
$accountprefix = 'storageaccount'

$nextNumber = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | 
    Where-Object {
        $_.StorageAccountName.StartsWith($accountprefix)
    } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.StorageAccountName -replace $accountprefix
    } | Measure-Object -Maximum

$newAccountName = '{0}{1}' -f $accountprefix, ($nextNumber.Maximum +1).ToString("#00")
```

Comment: this seems to be what I need to do however I'm getting this error when trying to run the code : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:19 char:1
+ $newAccountName = '{0}{1}' -f $accountprefix, $nextNumber.Maximum.ToS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Did you login to Azure using Login-AzureRmAccount first? I tried the script and it works without any issue.

Comment: ok it works! don't know what I was doing wrong earlier but it works okay..thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting one of the provided answer using the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name 'ContosoStorage03'
```

for this to check if the storage account name `ContosoStorage03` is available.

You could make a loop and write

```
$index = 0; 

while($true) 
{
    $name="contoso$index";
    $resp = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name $name;

    if($resp.NameAvailable) { break; }

    $index++;
}

Write-Host "index: $index"
```

Comment: This is a great solution if its okay that he wants to reuse numbers for e. g. deleted projects. So if ContosoStorage06 is the current but ContosoSotrage02 was removed, then his new project could use 02.